# Global variable is not being assigned outside the function

Tags: jquery

i am assigning value to a global variable, but, this is not working inside the function, i am assigning value to the global variable inside the function, i am displaying that value outside of a function. but, value is not coming.  Any help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>eq demo</title>
        <style>
            div, .sectiontitle {
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                margin: 10px;
                float: left;
                border: 2px solid blue;
            }
            .blue {
                background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul class="mainnav" id="mainnav1">
            <li><a href="/Home.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/Test-Orders/Home.aspx"><span>Test orders</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/Access-Arrangements/Home.aspx"><span>Access arrangements</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/Pupils/Home.aspx"><span>Pupil registration</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/Teacher-Assessment/Home.aspx" class="active"><span>Teacher assessment</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/Pupil-results/Home.aspx?stage=2"><span>Pupil results</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/Phonics/Home.aspx"><span>Phonics screening check</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            // this is a global variable
            globalVar = "";
            $(function() {

                $("#mainnav1 li a").click(function() {
                    globalVar = $(this).find('span').text();
                    alert(globalVar); //here, the value is coming
                });
                alert(globalVar); //here, the value is not coming, i need value of global variable
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why would it alert outside the handler, that code won't just rerun. Your variable is set and your code is fine./

Comment: i am treating that as a global variable am using that in some other place. i need that variable value outside function. any help?

Comment: The other place should be in a handler, also. Everything that isn't in a handler is only run when the page first loads.

Comment: Unrelated: don't declare variables without `var`! If you want to declare a global variable, either declare it with `var` in global scope, or set it as a property of `window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is working perfectly fine. You are setting `globalVar="";` so when the page loads and runs `alert(globalVar);` it comes up blank. When you have the click event it changes `globalVar`. However, it is not going to rerun that other call. That was a onetime deal. If you create another hook to view the `globalVar` value, you will see.

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0qxbtva5/

Comment: it seems it is not working as i expected, the first alert only displaying the value not the outer one, i need that outer one.

Comment: Right now you are only calling it on page load. You have the alert for when the link is clicked and that is working. So, what would you like to trigger that outside call?

Comment: i am using the variable to another round of checking in some other function, thats why i am confirming it by alerting it. hope this make sense.

Comment: Here is an updated Fiddle showing how the global variable is being set and is available to other functions: http://jsfiddle.net/0qxbtva5/1/